# How to import modules during tests using jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsx, enzyme

I'm using React, Enzyme and Jest. This is my connect component which only renders a button

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import PlaidLinkButton from 'react-plaid-link-button';


const plaidEnv = process.env.REACT_APP_PLAID_ENV

export class ConnectStep extends Component {

  handleOnSuccessBroker = async (token, metadata) => {
    //unimportant
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <PlaidLinkButton
          buttonProps={{
            className: classes.connectButton,
            id: 'button',
          }}
          plaidLinkProps={{
            clientName: '###',
            key: '###',
            env: plaidEnv,
            product: ['transactions'],
            onSuccess: this.handleOnSuccessBroker,
            token: ''
          }}
        >
          {this.props.plaid.accounts.length > 0 ? 'CONNECTED' : 'Start'}
            </PlaidLinkButton>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see Im importing PlaidLinkButton but jest throws this error:

```
    ###/node_modules/react-plaid-link-button/dist/react-plaid-link-button/react-plaid-link-button.js:19
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
           ^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

      4 | 
      5 | import { setPlaid } from '../../../actions/actions';
    > 6 | import PlaidLinkButton from 'react-plaid-link-button';
```

What am I missing? I made successful test suites for other components that also import modules. But this one in particular is giving me problems.

Comment: why do you need to import PlaidLinkButton into the test? aren't you just shallow rendering ConnectStep?? I'd like to see the whole test file too

Comment: I dont need to that is what Im trying to avoid. Im indeed shallow rendering. Thats what I couldnt figure out about this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
           ^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

This is likely an issue related to your Jest/Babel config because the modules aren't getting compiled correctly. You'd need to remove anywhere you set the Babel option [modules](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#modules) to `false`.

Related: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14399

Comment: I think youre right for what I read but I cant find where the Babel configuration is. Im using create-react-app.

Comment: Just making sure... what version of react-scripts are you using?

Comment: Also, please include your package.json here if you've made any changes to it.